# Como colocar variável PHP com valor menor e maior (min e max)

Tags: php

Olá, pessoal!

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de fazer uma variável em PHP com um numeral min e max, por exemplo:

$var = /*um numeral maior ou igual a 10 OU um numeral menor ou igual a 20*/;

Existe alguma forma de fazer isto direto na variável sem ter que usar if ou semelhantes?

Agradeço desde já. Obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Se quiser um número aleatório:

```
$var = rand( 10, 20 );
```

Manual:

> [`int rand ( int $min , int $max )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php)

### Se quiser aplicar a um valor já existente

```
$var = max( min( $var, 20 ), 10 );
```

Manual:

> [`mixed min ( mixed $value1 , mixed $value2 [, mixed $... ] )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.min.php)
>   [`mixed max ( mixed $value1 , mixed $value2 [, mixed $... ] )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.max.php)

Comment: obrigado, mas me diga: está dando o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined variable: rma_d in /storage/emulated/legacy/www/CTS/decode.php on line 55

Comment: Esse erro não tem relação nem com o que foi perguntado, nem com o que eu respondi. Você está tentando usar uma variável que não foi definida no seu código.

Comment: Hahaha saquei. Posso te passar o código para que possa entender melhor minha situação? Seria algo do tipo: http://pastebin.com/mrMmracG

Comment: Seguinte... seu código não tem muito a ver tambem. Quando fizer uma pergunta, não adianta querer simplificar demais. Poderia ter posto o código logo na pergunta, e dado uma explicação detalhada do que quer (com um exemplo do que é pra ter na saída). Até a parte de separar os números em grupos, deu pra entender mais ou menos o que quer, sobre a parte de pegar os nomes depois, já não ficou muito claro. Sugiro você criar uma nova pergunta explicando o que você precisa fazer exatamente (explicando o problema, e não o jeito que você acha que vai resolver, pois pode não ser o melhor caminho)

Comment: Umas dicas de leitura, antes de fazer a pergunta: [Tour], [Ask] e com muita atenção, [O que é o problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499).

Comment: Tudo bem. Muito obrigado, amigo :D